# Psychology behind for historical bias

Tags: social-psychology

There is lot of movement in India currently going on [rewriting history](https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/india-modi-culture/)

dealing with topics such as [Aryan Invasion Theory](https://www.change.org/p/honourable-minister-hrd-govt-of-india-the-aryan-invasion-theory-a-myth-indian-history-has-to-be-retold) and [Ramayana and Mahabharatha](https://www.outlookindia.com/magazine/story/ramayana-mahabharata-are-true-accounts-of-the-periodnot-myths/291363)

I am guessing similar such ideas may be around the world on presenting their local history correctly. My question is not on the justification of these movements or the truth behind it but I am rather wondering if there a known human psychology which makes this need of a person that their ancestors belong to an "elite history". If so, what is it?

Why would it be important for a present day person what their ancestors did or where did they come from? Why a glorified history of their ancestors 1000 of years back is important?

Again, my question is not actually it is true or not but mainly trying to understand human psychology where search for "true history" is mainly a need for one to be "special". Is it just the need to be proud about something or something more deeper? This need is often bigger than the need to find "truth".  Being open to accept that their ancestors or their favourite historical heroes could have done something wrong is simply out of question.

My question is simply why do people care if someone who lived in different era but in their neighbourhood was a "hero" or "not".  Why are they not as neutral or objective as they would be for someone in foreign land.

This is my first question here so please let me know if I need to edit it to make it more appropriate for this site.